# Code 1 is not working but the other is. What is wrong with 1st code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript. For the life of me I can't tell what is wrong with my object code below. I get an error saying:

> this.signIn is not a function

```
let socialAppFunctions = {
  displayNewsFeed: function () {
    let socialPostsSection = document.querySelector("#socialPosts");

    newsFeed.forEach(function (posts) {
      let socialPosts = document.createElement("h4");
      socialPosts.textContent = posts;
      socialPostsSection.appendChild(socialPosts);
    });
  },
  loginButton: function () {
    let loginButton = document.querySelector("#loginButton");

    loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

      let userName = document.querySelector("#user");
      let passWord = document.querySelector("#pass");

      this.signIn(userName.value, passWord.value);

    });
  },
  signIn: function (username, password) {

    if (this.userValidation(username, password)) {
        this.displayNewsFeed();
      } else {
        alert("Please check username and password");
      }
  },
  userValidation: function (username, password) {

    for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
      if (database[i].username === username && database[i].password === password) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

socialAppFunctions.loginButton();
```

This one below works if I don't put them as inside as one object:

```
function signIn (username, password) {

      if (userValidation(username, password)) {
        displayNewsFeed();
      } else {
        alert("Please check username and password");
      }
    }

function userValidation (username, password) {

    for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
      if (database[i].username === username && database[i].password === password) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


function loginButton () {
    let loginButton = document.querySelector("#loginButton");

    loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

      let userName = document.querySelector("#user");
      let passWord = document.querySelector("#pass");

      signIn(userName.value, passWord.value);

    });
  }
loginButton();

function displayNewsFeed () {
    let socialPostsSection = document.querySelector("#socialPosts");

    newsFeed.forEach(function (posts) {
      let socialPosts = document.createElement("h4");
      socialPosts.textContent = posts;
      socialPostsSection.appendChild(socialPosts);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the context of `this` keyword within your addEventListener block in the above code.

The value of `this` will refer to `loginButton` inside the add event listener and `loginButton` doesnt have a signIn method, to make your code still work you need to bind `this` by doing the following.

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

      let userName = document.querySelector("#user");
      let passWord = document.querySelector("#pass");

      this.signIn(userName.value, passWord.value);

    }.bind(this));
```

And now `this` inside addEventListener block will refer to `socialAppFunctions` object and it would work.